# Is there any case in which AppWidget id may change?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I've created a Memo AppWidget. I save the content of the memo to a shared preference based on the appWidgetId of the AppWidget.

This works, but I am afraid that if I use multiple AppWidgets the id may change at some point in the future, as this would cause my application to crash.

Is there any possibility that an appWidget id could change in the future (like on reboot, reinstall app, etc)?

Comment: Could you please group your question in paragraphs? It is very difficult to read a question where every sentence is on its own line.

Comment: Have you got the answer yet?

Comment: Old question, I don't see why this is an unreasonable question. I think you're answer is in [App Widget Host docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/host.html). Specifically "This ID is persistent across the lifetime of the widget, that is, until it is deleted from the host."